# Error when trying to simultaneously describe icon and packages to cx_Freeze

Tags: pygame, cx-freeze

I am trying to freeze a Python 3.7 script using pygame to an exe file (and build a .msi installer) using cx_Freeze with the command *python setup.py bdist_msi*, on my Windows 10 computer.

I can successfully build the exe with cx_Freeze without specifying an icon, and I can also build an exe from an empty python script but with my app_icon.ico icon. That second exe does have the icon so my ico file seems to be valid. But doing both at the same time (adding the `icon=icon.ico` option in cx_Freeze's `Executable(...)`) causes the following error quickly after copying some libraries to the build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\ folder :

```
running bdist_msi
running build
running build_exe
creating directory build\exe.win-amd64-3.7
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Console.exe -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\test.exe
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\python37.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\python37.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\VCRUNTIME140.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\VCRUNTIME140.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
copying c:\users\alexandre\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
error: [WinError 2] Le fichier spcifi est introuvable: 'build\\exe.win-amd64-3.7\\test.exe'
```

The last line being French for "The specified file cannot be found:".

Here is the minimal example I came up with.

I have a folder Test\ containing an icon app_icon.ico, an empty test.py file and this setup.py file :

```
import cx_Freeze

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Test",
    options={"build_exe":
                {
                    "packages":["pygame"],
                    "include_files": ["app_icon.ico"],
                },
            },
    executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable(script="test.py",
                                        #icon="app_icon.ico"
                                    )
    ]
)
```

Note that trying to omit `"packages":["pygame"]` in setup.py while using the module in the test.py file will cause the same problem (I guess writing `"packages":["pygame"]` is not necessary as cx_Freeze will detect pygame if it is used).

Uncommenting `icon="app_icon.ico"` causes the error, and then commenting `"packages":["pygame"]` removes it.

As a last but perplexing detail: if I choose to build my exe (with my original full python code for the game but without the icon), I can still make a shortcut of it (manually, or with the options `shortcutName = "Nurikabe", shortcutDir = "DesktopFolder"`). It will have a default icon. I can change it with right click (on the desktop shortcut), properties, change icon. When clicking change icon, it will always tell me

> the following file was not found : %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Installer{a long hexadecimal name}...\app_icon.ico

Which is strange as I would expect the exe to look for its icon in the TargetDir or wherever the exe is installed in, but not that %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Installer\ folder. I tried installing the exe folder to different locations but the same Microsoft\Installer not found error always comes back. And even though, I can click "ok" to close that error message, then click Browse to look manually for a custom ico file. If I eventually select my app_icon.ico icon, it is accepted and becomes the icon for the shortcut.

Before I end, my problem has nothing to do with missing mkl_* libraries, a recurring problem in SO topics related to cx_Freeze and pygame. I include them in my iconless app which works fine. My problem really is about the icon that seems to be allergic to pygame.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved that problem by adding modules to the `"excludes"` key of `cx_Freeze.setup()`'s `options` argument and removing nonessential mkl_*.dll 's in the setup.py file. Something there was interfering between pygame et my icon, and that thing was not even necessary in the exe!

I came to this solution by noticing that having a 1.1GB app was probably way too much and I could surely remove some of the heavy modules imported by cx_Freeze to the .\lib folder of the app. Not only my app is 9 times lighter now, but the icon doesn't make cx_Freeze fail anymore.

For future reference, my setup.py file now looks like this:

```
import cx_Freeze
import os

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))

#this line was previously the list of all mkl_* dlls, plus libiomp5md.dll
mkl_dlls = ["mkl_intel_thread.dll", "mkl_core.dll", "libiomp5md.dll"]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="...",
    author= "...",
    description="...",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["os", "pygame"],
                            "excludes":["babel", "cryptography", "Cython", "distutils", "docutils", "IPython", "jedi", "llvmlite", "lxml", "markupsafe", "matplotlib", "mkl", "nbconvert", "numba", "numpy", "PIL", "prompt_toolkit", "psutil", "PyQt5", "pytest", "pytz", "scipy", "sphinx", "tkinter", "tornado", "win32com", "zmq"]+["libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll", "sqlite3.dll"],
                            "include_files":
                                ["app_icon.ico","other specific files to include"]+[os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR,"Library","bin",i) for i in mkl_dlls]
                        },
            },
    executables = [
            cx_Freeze.Executable(script="my main script.py",
                base="Win32GUI",
                targetName = "... .exe",
                icon="app_icon.ico",
                shortcutName = "...",
                shortcutDir = "DesktopFolder"
            ),
            cx_Freeze.Executable("my second script.py")
            ]
    )

# python setup.py build         to build the exe
# python setup.py bdist_msi     to create an msi
```